# Convert ptime to std::string

Tags: c++, boost, time

How do I convert boost ptime to std string? I tried multiple ways and I'm getting compile time errors. But according to [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) it should be possible to do this.

```
std::string function()
{
    now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

    return std::string(now);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal working example

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34793732b1a7bb24)**

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters_limited.hpp" 

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;

    ptime now = second_clock::local_time();
    std::cout << to_simple_string(now) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: He didn't claim it should be in the `std` namespace either, right? He just tried to _construct_ a `std::string` there :) (hope you don't mind me making it _more_ minimal)

Comment: @sehe I think the post was edited, I think the original question had `std::to_string(now)`... but maybe it's because I'm tired :-)

Comment: @sehe you are right, I see now that the question has not been edited, if it had there would be an `edited` link... I removed the comment about `std` thanks for pointing that out.  Nice link to Coliru, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @sehe minimal is good, speaking of which, you can now take out the #include <string>.

Comment: Technically, of course, we're not supposed to rely on indirect inclusions. They're implementation details ^.^